# Problems in coding small straight for Yahtzee game

Tags: c++

So this is for a school assignment obviously, and for some reason I can not wrap my head around coding to calculate a [small straight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee#Small_Straight) for the game of yahtzee. I have done all the coding for all the other possible rolls except this one. I know this is a question asked a lot but i cant find a simple answer anywhere. I need to be able to do it using if, for, and while loops. If anyone can help it would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Please post your code which include your effort

Comment: Please explain what a "small straight" is.

Comment: @PaulR http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg - I've edited a link into the question now to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the rolls and count the number of consecutive dice. If you have four then you have a small straight. If all five rolls are consecutive then you have a large straight.